# Reversing a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

Problem in Reversing  a linked list without using recursion.

I used this method, but when i try and run this back home, I am not able to print the reverse of the linked list even though the function looks good It goes on to print the linked list in the same way as it did earlier.

Can someone help me understand what is wrong here??

```
class link {
    int data;
    public link nextlink;

    link(int d1) {
        data = d1;
    }
}

class List{

    link head;
    link revhead;

    List(){
        head = null;
    }

    boolean isEmpty(link head) {
       return head==null;
    }

    void insert(int d1) {
        link templink = new link(d1);
        templink.nextlink = head;
        head = templink;
    }

    void printlist(){
        link head1 = head;
        while(!isEmpty(head1)) {
            System.out.print(head1.data + " ");
            head1 = head1.nextlink;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    void reverse() {
        link previous=null,temp=null;
        while(isEmpty(head)) {
            temp = head.nextlink;
            head.nextlink = previous;
            previous = head;
            head = temp;
        }
    }

}

public class LinkedList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List list1 = new List();

        list1.insert(10);
        list1.insert(20);
        list1.insert(30);
        list1.insert(40);
        list1.insert(50);
        list1.printlist();
        list1.reverse();
        list1.printlist();
     }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run it?  What did you see when you stepped through the code with a debugger?  Does it work on a linked list that's 0 items long? 1 item? 2 items?  If you make it work for 3, it will work for any number...

Comment: This code adds new entries to the list at the front, so if you run your printlist function, you should write out entries in the reverse order from how you added them. Is that not what you're trying to accomplish? Perhaps you need to clarify the question.

Comment: The aim of the code is to first create a linked list.
 50-40-30-20-10-NULL  
Then reverse it
 10-20-30-40-50-NULL

Comment: Now that this is done, I am wondering, howcan I reverse ever K elements, for a given value of K.

Comment: Can someone help me with reversing every K elements of a linked list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems in your code. One: you check for isEmpty(head) where as you should check for !isEmpty(head). Second: when you fix first problem, then 'head' becomes null when loop terminates.

The correct code with fix for above two problems:

```
void reverse() {
    link previous = null, temp = null;
    while (!isEmpty(head)) {
        temp = head.nextlink;
        head.nextlink = previous;
        previous = head;
        if (temp == null) {
           break;
        }
        head = temp;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, figured that out, but as I am new,cant paste answers before 8 hours :( Good that you caught that soon, it took me a lot of time to catch the error, thanks!

Comment: Now that this is done, I am wondering, how can I reverse ever K elements, for a given value of K.

Comment: You mean reversing first K elements? If so, you want to leave other elements after first K elements as they are?

Comment: HI Niraj, I was working on reversing K elemnts and ran into this unusual error!

Answer (score 0):

check your condition:
 while (isEmpty(head))

you forgot to add the "!"  you meant while not empty... do

Comment: Yes I figured that out, along with one more problem,thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0):

Consider what the recursive method does when you're printing the links.  It doesn't actually do anything until it has them all (i.e. it's placing each call on the stack, then when the base case is reached, it pops elements from the stack).

What non-stack structure do you have readily available that could be used to store the reverse of the list, then let you print it out?

Comment: If you look at the correction above, it can be done without using recursion.

Comment: I'm well aware of that.  My answer doesn't give code, but rather encourages the OP to think about how they want to go about their solution - code isn't necessary when you're talking concepts.

Comment: then i have a question to you, What is a better approach, My little experience tells me that one should avoid using the stack if there is an iterative solution at hand. What is your say on this.

Comment: It depends on how many operations you would do recursively, and how large your stack is.  Ideally, for this operation, you would want to do it iteratively, since one can't tell if the list will expand to a size larger than the stack.  It may be *easier* and *cleaner* to express a solution recursively, but doing it iteratively would be less calls on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

The corrected Code for reversing a Linked list without recursion.

```
class Link {

    int data;
    public Link nextLink;

    Link(int d1) {
        data = d1;
    }
}

class List {

    Link head;
    Link revhead;

    List() {
        head = null;
    }

    boolean isEmpty(Link head) {
        return head == null;
    }

    void insert(int d1) {
        Link tempLink = new Link(d1);
        tempLink.nextLink = head;
        head = tempLink;
    }

    void printlist() {
        Link head1 = head;
        while (!isEmpty(head1)) {
            System.out.print(head1.data + " ");
            head1 = head1.nextLink;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    void reverse() {
        Link previous = null, temp = null;
        while (!isEmpty(head)) {
            temp = head.nextLink;
            head.nextLink = previous;
            previous = head;
            head = temp;
        }

        head = previous;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List list1 = new List();

        list1.insert(10);
        list1.insert(20);
        list1.insert(30);
        list1.insert(40);
        list1.insert(50);
        list1.printlist();
        list1.reverse();
        list1.printlist();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Node {
    Node next;
    int value;

    public Node() {
    }

    public Node(Node next, int value) {
        super();
        this.next = next;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}

public class Linkedlist {
    private Node head = null;

    public Linkedlist(Node head) {
        this.head = head;
    }

    public void iterate() {
        Node current = head;
        while (current != null) {
            System.out.println(current.getValue());
            current = current.getNext();
        }
    }

    public void reverse() {
        Node current = head;
        Node prev = null;
        while (current != null) {
            Node temp = current.next;
            current.next = prev;
            prev = current;
            current = temp;
        }
        head = prev;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node n = new Node(null, 10);
        Node n1 = new Node(n, 20);
        Node n2 = new Node(n1, 30);
        Node n3 = new Node(n2, 40);
        Node n4 = new Node(n3, 50);
        Node n5 = new Node(n4, 60);
        Linkedlist linkedlist = new Linkedlist(n5);
        linkedlist.iterate();
        linkedlist.reverse();
        System.out.println("------------------REVERSED---------------------");
        linkedlist.iterate();

    }
}
```