# Reversing LinkedList using do While Loop

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to reverse a List (Created by Using Class ElementL) as follow, I am able to reverse it using following but last element is skipped while reversing.

```
public static ElementL reverse(ElementL element){
        //Implement reverse here

        ElementL previous = null;
        ElementL next = element.next;

        do{
            element.next = previous;
            previous = element;
            element = next;
            next = next.next;
        }while(next!=null);

        return  previous;
    }
```

Last element is being skipped because of condition in While loop which checks if next element is null or not.  Can somebody suggest change to existing code such that condition in while can be modified to do reverse on all elements.

For Reference, Structure of Class ElementL

```
public class ElementL{ 
        ElementL next;
        int data;


        public ElementL(int data){
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this logic:-

```
ElementL previous = null;
ElementL next = null;
do {
    next = element.next;
    element.next = previous;
    previous = element;
    element = next;
} while (next != null);

return previous;
```

The only thing you need to look after is that, `element` is not null initially!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
    public static ElementL reverse(ElementL element){
            //Implement reverse here

```
        ElementL previous = null;
        ElementL next = element.next;

        do{
            element.next = previous;
            previous = element;
            element = next;
            if (next != null)
               next = next.next;
        }while(element!=null);

        return  previous;
    }
```

Comment: Can we do without if(next != null), Can you put some ternary condition in While() whiche will increment and check ?

Comment: It can be done by changing the order of your statements. You can see RJ's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your own custom code, you can just use [`java.util.Collections.reverse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29).

Comment: The purpose is to learn how it works :), thanks for the reply, I removed java tag

Answer (score 0):

Try this
public static ElementL reverse(ElementL element){
    //Implement reverse here

```
ElementL previous = null;
ElementL next = null;

do{
    next = element.next;
    element.next = previous;
    previous = element;
    element = next;

}while(element!=null);

return  previous;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
class Node {
    private Node next;
    private int value;

    public Node() {
    }

    public Node(Node next, int value) {
        super();
        this.next = next;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}

public class Linkedlist {
    private Node head = null;

    public Linkedlist(Node head) {
        this.head = head;
    }

    public void iterate() {
        Node current = head;
        while (current != null) {
            System.out.println(current.getValue());
            current = current.getNext();
        }
    }

    public void reverse() {
        Node current = head;
        Node prev = null;
        while (current != null) {
            Node temp = current.getNext();
            current.setNext(prev);
            prev = current;
            current = temp;
        }
        head = prev;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node n = new Node(null, 10);
        Node n1 = new Node(n, 20);
        Node n2 = new Node(n1, 30);
        Node n3 = new Node(n2, 40);
        Node n4 = new Node(n3, 50);
        Node n5 = new Node(n4, 60);
        Linkedlist linkedlist = new Linkedlist(n5);
        linkedlist.iterate();
        linkedlist.reverse();
        System.out.println("------------------REVERSED---------------------");
        linkedlist.iterate();

    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't copy and paste the same [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640812/reversing-a-linked-list/35537137#35537137) to multiple questions. Each answer should be modified to answer that particular question. It also helps if you provide more than a block of code and explain what the code is doing.