# Reversing a doubly linked list in Java without creating new list

Tags: java, pointers, reverse, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to reverse a doubly linked list in Java and can't seem to figure out why I am getting NullPointer errors. I know that there are other questions on here which deal with the same topic such as

[Reversing a Doubly Linked List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166968/reversing-a-doubly-linked-list)

[Reversing a linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640812/reversing-a-linked-list)

and a few others that I have found.

I am sorry for the duplicate but I think what I am doing is the same as what the answers advise and I can't seem to figure out why my function isn't working.

I know that I need to traverse the list and swap the pointers for next and previous until I reach the end of the list, which should result in the list being reversed.

Here is the code for my function:

```
    public void reverse() {

        Node<AnyType> temp = null;
        //Start at the beginning of the list
        Node<AnyType> current = beginMarker;
        //Go until the end of the list is reached
        while (current !=  null)
        {
            //Update temp to remember what came before the current node
            temp = current.prev;
            //Then switch the previous and next pointers
            current.prev = current.next;
            current.next = temp;  
            //Advance current to point to the next node in the list, which is now 
            //stored in current.prev           
            current = current.prev;
        }      
}
```

and this is what I think I am doing:

Creating a temp variable to hold the value of the next the previous value for when I make a swap, initially set to null because the last node should have a pointer to null for node.next, and a current variable to hold where I am currently in the list.

Then while current is not null, so while I am not at the end of the list, I am setting the temp variable to what came before current. Then I'm swapping the pointers for previous and next, and setting the new value of current to `current.prev`, which should move me forward a node in the list.

However there must be something that I am missing here. I would appreciate being pushed in the right direction.

Edit: 
This is my stack trace but it is not giving me an error within the function so I'm not sure how exactly to read it to find where the issue is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MyLinkedList$LinkedListIterator.next(MyLinkedList.java:285)
    at MyLinkedList.toString(MyLinkedList.java:186)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2847)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:821)
    at MyLinkedList.main(MyLinkedList.java:321)
```

Comment: Here's small [tutorial](https://keysersblog.wordpress.com/2014/04/21/debugging-java-code-a-beginners-guide/) on debugging java code that I wrote. It sounds like it could help. Short version: The stack trace has some information you want, and you could add some prints or use a debugger to further investigate.

Comment: You forget to store the *new* head pointer (next-but-last value of current in the loop) as the new list pointer. So main, trying to print the reversed string, runs into a NPE (guessing a wee bit here). The reverse internals are essentially OK. Not `void reverse` but `Node<AnyType> reverse`!

Comment: Well, it doesn't give you an error inside the function cause the function isn't crashing. The word to note is `next`, and checking out that line could help, along with some printing. Like I said, investigate. I guess @laune is right though, but, for the future.

Comment: What you want to do after making it in reverse order ?.. you can iterate it in reverse order when you want to use the arraylist